# Do test files get bundled with the code in react native?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, metro-bundler

I was just wondering whether the unit test files that we write also get bundled together in the final apk and ipa file in react native. If that is the case how can we exclude such test files from getting bundled. Is there some configuration that we can do in the metro file to prevent the test files from being bundled by the metro bundler?

Answer (score 0):

### Seems to Not true in `0.72.1`

I am using RN `0.72.1` and tested about it.

It seems to RN automatically exclude module like that

- placed in `/src` but has suffix `.test.*` or something like that.

Not only release build, but development metro hot reload environment shows that.

```
// Sample.test.tsx

export const Sample = 123;

// Sample.tsx

<Text>{`Import from test file in src: ${Sample}`}</Text>
```

[image]

[another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75198084/how-does-react-native-know-to-ignore-test-files-during-compilation)